# Equivalent definitions of the multiplier algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

For a $C^*$-algebra $A$, G.J. Murphy (in his book page 38) Defines the multiplier algebra $M(A)$ of $A$ to be the set of its double centralizers.

In this [book](https://books.google.ca/books/about/A_Course_in_Commutative_Banach_Algebras.html?id=Sp5uwaZsQLAC&redir_esc=y), they define $M(A)$ as the collection of all mapping $T:A \rightarrow A$ such that for any $x ,y \in A$, $x(Ty)=(Tx)y$.(Definition 1.4.10)

Another definition is [This](http://nlab-pages.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/nlab/show/multiplier+algebra) by the universal property.

Are there other definitions that are equivalent to the above or somehow related?

Comment: Try looking at the references in the link you provided.

Comment: I also found another description [here](https://www.fuw.edu.pl/~slworono/PDF-y/OP.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many equivalent definitions of the multiplier algebra $M(A)$. I'll list some, but I'll only describe the underlying sets.

$(1)$ The set of double centralizers $(L,R)$ which consist of maps $A\to A$ satisfying $R(a)b = aL(b)$ for all $a,b \in A$.

$(2)$ (Essentially the same as $(1)$) The set of maps $L: A \to A$ for which there exists a map $R: A \to A$ such that $R(a)b = aL(b)$ for all $a,b \in A$.

$(3)$ View the $C^*$-algebra $A$ as a right Hilbert module over itself in the obvious way. Then we can define $M(A) = \mathcal{L}_A(A)$, the $A$-adointable operators.

$(4)$ The multiplier $C^*$-algebra as the solution to a universal problem: $M(A)$ is the largest $C^*$-algebra that contains the $C^*$-algebra $A$ as an essential two-sided ideal, in the sense that if $j: A \to C$ is a $*$-morphism with $j(A)$ an essential ideal in $C$, there exists a unique $*$-morphism $M(A) \to C$ extending the map $j:A \to C$.

$(5)$ If $A \subseteq B(H)$ is a faithful non-degenerate $*$-representation (we can also represent on a Hilbert module instead of a Hilbert space), we can define
$$M(A) = \{x \in B(H): x A \subseteq A \text{ and } Ax \subseteq A\}\subseteq B(H).$$

All these interpretations are canonically $*$-isomorphic. The way to see this is to show that each one of them satisfies the universal property satisfied in $(4)$ (though it is immediately clear that the interpretations $(1), (2), (3)$ give the same $C^*$-algebra). A good reference to see the equivalence $(3) \iff (4) \iff (5)$ (which is basically the interesting part) is Lance's book "Hilbert $C^*$-modules" chapter 2.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer.